# Variable 'pathname' Issue with ngRoute

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I've been searching the forum for an issue similar to mine but haven't had any luck. However I have found a solution I'm going to share.

My problem was when I want to change my route it doesn't direct me to the correct location. For instance my url is www.dnndev.me/Projects/Project#/dashboard. I tried to create a few links like so:

```
// goes to www.dnndev.me#/tasks.
<a ng-href="#/task"></a>
// same as above however what's between my {{}} is rendered blank.
<a ng-href="{{window.location.pathname}}#/task"></a>
```

'window.location.pathname' provides the missing piece of my url but it won't render. I thought about storing this in a variable but that didn't seem very Angular to me.

I tried using $location but it has no pathname property. I did come across $location.path('path) and it did what I needed. However I did not care to inject every controller with the $location service. After thinking for a bit I came up with an idea to create a function on the $rootscope in my applications run function and it does what I need.

```
# this is written in coffeescript
run = ['$location', '$rootScope', ($location, $rootScope) ->
    $rootScope.route = (path) ->
        $location.path(path)

//html
<button ng-click="$root.route('task')">
</button>
```

The reason I need this is because 'pathname' is variable. I'm working in the DNN framework and this module could be dropped on any path such as 'www.website.com/foo/bar#/dashboard'.

Is there a better way to acomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $location.path to navigate with the info you have provided.

```
$location.path('/task');
```

And this /task should be mapped in your routing. You dont have to worry about anything. Something like below,

```
$routeProvider.when('/task', {
    templateUrl : "where you wish to navigate", // This should be replaced by your need
    controller : "taskController"
})
```